# How to turn off autosaving password popup in each browser using Vuejs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Literally, I want to turn off password saving popup in the browser.
Many answers said that use autoComplete. But I think autoComplete doesnt' work anymore.
I want to know the recent technic for this problem.
Could you recommend some advice for this?
Thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I do it

On submit:

1. Save the password from the input field
2. Clear the password input field
3. Set the input field to type="text"
4. handle the form submission using AJAX

This works 100% - but is a little fiddly - though, easy enough

here's how you could handle a bit easier than I described - given you aren't doing any AJAX in your login

```
<form action="/login" method="post" name="loginform">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="password" name="input_password" />
  <input type="hidden" name="password" />
  <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>

document.forms.loginform.addEventListener('submit', function() {
  const {
    input_password,
    password
  } = this.elements;
  password.value = input_password.value;
  input_password.value = '';
  input_password.type = 'text';
});
```

If your login already does some AJAX, then the principal is the same, but you won't need a hidden field

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But Can you make your saying by code? It's bcz I can understand well through code.

Comment: @DDDD - depending on how your login form works, the solution is slightly easier, you just need a hidden field

Comment: How can change element type in vuje?

Comment: @DDDD If you meant vue or vuejs then that's very easy - I take it you're not "submitting a form" in vue

Comment: I'd show an example, but I can't get to my code at the moment!

Answer (score 2):

it's not something you can do in your own code, it's a browser behavior, You can only achieve this by changing your browser settings. [disable browser password manager](https://support.1password.com/disable-browser-password-manager/)

If you want to do it in your code, I think you can try something like, do not give your input element attributes `name`, `id`, `type` common value - do not name them as `password`, `email`, etc, to cheat the browser build-in password saving feature.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you give me one input tag cheating browser?

Comment: but `type` has to be `password` for a password field, also, giving attributes like id and name other names does not help at all